# Writing to StorageFile concurrently

Tags: c#, concurrency, windows-phone-8.1

How can I write some text to a StorageFile concurrently in Windows Phone 8.1? I tried to implement mutex provided by `lock` in C#, but I'm unable to open the stream of the file that I want to write to under in the `lock` block.

This is what I'm doing:

```
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(logFileName);
// Lock file access object and open filestream for writing.
lock (fileLockObject)
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync());
    writer.Write(sometext);
}
```

But `lock` doesn't allow any kind of `async` operation in it's body. How can I still maintain mutex and concurrency without using some third-party library like `AsyncLock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using Semaphores. I used `SlimSemaphore()` to acquire and release a semaphore with a single resource before and writing to file. This enabled use of await operation and removed the limitations associated with `lock` and `mutex` as you can run `await` operations in the block (which `mutex` and `lock` don't really allow).

```
// define semaphore with only one resource to allocate.
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

// acquire semaphore 
await semaphore.WaitAsync();

try { // write to file }
catch { // catch any exception }
finally
{
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the best way. There is no question about it.

Answer (score 2):

In `async` operations you need use **`AsyncLock`** instead `lock`

```
    private readonly AsyncLock asyncLocker = new AsyncLock();
    .....
    using(await asyncLocker.LockAsync())
    {
       enter code here
    }
```

AsyncLock [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx), [github](https://github.com/andriikrupka/StrangeToolkit/blob/master/StrangeToolkitLibraries/StrangeToolkit.Core/Synchonization/AsyncLock.cs)

Answer (score 2):

Usually in this scenario you want the writes to be in order as much as possible and you want to offload the actual writing to another single thread. Below is a simplified example however in most cases you will want to optimize it to end and restart the thread when needed.

```
    AutoResetEvent _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    List<string> _writeCache = new List<string>();
    bool _threadRunning = false;

    void WriteToFile(string text)
    {
        lock (_writeCache)
        {
            _writeCache.Add(text);
            _waitHandle.Set();

            if(_threadRunning)
            {
                return;
            }
            _threadRunning = true;
        }

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                _waitHandle.WaitOne();

                StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(logFileName);
                using (var f = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()))
                    {
                        lock (_writeCache)
                        {
                            while (_writeCache.Count > 0)
                            {
                                string s = _writeCache[0];
                                _writeCache.RemoveAt(0);
                                writer.Write(s);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do need to use a `lock` statement, you could try:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public async Task WriteToFile(string text)
{
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(logFileName);

    lock (fileLockObject)
    {
        Task<Stream> streamTask = file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

        try
        {
            streamTask.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
             // You may want to handle errors here
        }

        if (!streamTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(streamTask.Result))
            {
                writer.Write(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage (supposed this is an event handler, else use `public async Task YourMethod(...)`):

```
public async void YourMethod()
{
    // 1. Blocks UI thread
    Task t = WriteToFile("text");

    t.Wait();
    // or
    // 2. Does not block UI thread
    await WriteToFile("text");
}
```

Comment: @AndriiKrupka Edited post due to your comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
public static void WriteLog(string Error)
{
    using (StreamWriter logfile = new StreamWriter(filePath + "Log.txt", true))
    {
        logfile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + " -@: " + Error);
        logfile.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `StreamWriter()` requires `Stream` type as the first argument.

Comment: @Flipper Create a Log text file and give the file path as first argument it will get the stream.